Does the Lomax model describes enzyme kinetics?
I´m here looking for empirical experience over this revelation, which surely is not so amazing but better call biology experts.
I recently founded the Lomax Probability Distribution and noted that the cumulative distribution function $L(x)$ has a very similar form related to the Michaelis-Menten Kinetics rate equation $v(S)$. This since:
$$L(x) = P(X \leq x) = 1 - \Big[1+\dfrac{x}{\lambda}\Big] ^{-\alpha}$$
and
$$v(S)=\dfrac{V_{max}S}{K_m+S}$$
Are, in fact, the same equation with $\alpha = 1$ and $\lambda = K_m$ since $L(x=S) = \dfrac{v(S)}{V_{max}}$.
Can this equation be used to model enzyme kinetic rates?
Does you have applied it?
P.D. I´ve never heard of an application of Pareto-related distributions in enzyme kinetics, so maybe it is a good start for modeling biochemical processes. Specifically, since $\lambda = K_m$, we could use experimental data to model this interaction with more precision (maybe) since a model that allows uncertainty is unlike lambert/regression solutions that are only deterministic.

The kinetics of enzyme reactions are determined by their mechanism of action, which vary considerably. The general approach taken is to elucidate the mechanism experimentally and then apply mathematics to it, making various assumptions. It is not, as far as I am aware, to attempt to fit it to some abstract mathematical model.
